# In gedit, highlight a function call within the parenthesis

Tags: regex, recursion, syntax-highlighting, gedit

I'm currently editing my javascript.lang file to highlight function names. 
Here is my expression for gtksourceview that I am currently using.

```
<define-regex id="function-regex" >
(?&lt;=([\.|\s]))
([a-z]\w*)
(?=([\(].*))(?=(.*[\)]))
</define-regex>
```

here's the regex by itself

```
(?<=([\.|\s]))([a-z]\w*)(?=([\(].*))(?=(.*[\)]))
```

It appears to work for situations such as, foo(A) which I am satisfied with.
But where I am having trouble is if I want it to highlight a function name within the parentheses of another function call.

```
  foo(bar(A))
```

or to put it more rigorously

```
  foo{N}(foo{N-1}(...(foo{2}(foo{1}(A))...))
```

So with the example,

```
  foo(bar(baz(A)))
```

my goal is for it to highlight foo, bar, baz and nothing else.

I don't know how to handle the bar function. I have read about a way of doing regex recursively with (?R) or (?0) but I have not had any success using that to highlight functions recursively in gedit.

P.S.
Here are the tests that I am currently using to determine success.

```
initialDrawGraph(toBeSorted);   
$(element).removeClass(currentclass);
myFrame.popStack();
context.outputCurrentSortOrder(V);
myFrame.nextFunction = sorter.Sort.;
context.outputToDivConsole(formatStr(V),1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like I was making this more complicated than it needed to be.

I was able to achieve what I needed with this simpler regex. I just told it to stop looking for the close parenthesis.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?=\()
```

Answer (score 1):

Balancing parentheses is not a regular expression, since it needs *memory* (See: [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)). For some implementations, there is an implementation for [*recursion* in regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html):

> ***Matching Balanced Constructs***
>
> The main purpose of recursion is to match balanced constructs or
>   nested constructs. The generic regex is `b(?:m|(?R))*e` where `b` is
>   what begins the construct, `m` is what can occur in the middle of the
>   construct, and `e` is what can occur at the end of the construct. For
>   correct results, no two of `b`, `m`, and `e` should be able to match
>   the same text. You can use an atomic group instead of the
>   non-capturing group for improved performance: `b(?>m|(?R))*e`.
>
> A common real-world use is to match a balanced set of parentheses.
>   `\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)` matches a single pair of parentheses with any
>   text in between, including an unlimited number of parentheses, as long
>   as they are all properly paired. If the subject string contains
>   unbalanced parentheses, then the first regex match is the leftmost
>   pair of balanced parentheses, which may occur after unbalanced opening
>   parentheses. If you want a regex that does not find any matches in a
>   string that contains unbalanced parentheses, then you need to use a
>   subroutine call instead of recursion. If you want to find a sequence
>   of multiple pairs of balanced parentheses as a single match, then you
>   also need a subroutine call.

Answer (score 0):

The following `regex` works for nested functions (Note: This is the python version of `regex`. You may or may not need to make some syntax tweaks. Hopefull, you'll get the idea):

[OBSOLETED] `'(\w+\()+[^\)]*\)+'`

[UPDATED] (Should Work. Hopefully)

`(\w+\()+([^\)]*\)+)*`

Comment: It looks like that regex has the problem where it simply highlights everything within the parentheses.

Comment: This solution breaks if you have anything _but_ `F1(F2(F3(...)))` - `F1(F2()+F3())` does not work for it

Comment: @joelliusp, Isn't that what you want. Or do you want to highlight only the function name or something?

Comment: @joelliusp, I updated my answer, Workds for Uri's case as well now.

Comment: @sshashank124 Correct. I am trying to highlight the function name only. I just edited my question to clear up that confusion hopefully.

Comment: @joelliusp, So in the case of `foo(bar(baz(A)))`, would you only want it to highlight `foo` or `foo`, `bar`, `baz` as well?

Comment: @sshashank124 The second one is my goal. foo, bar, and baz should all be highlighted and should be the only things highlighted.

Comment: @joelliuspm, Sorry for so many questions, but how are you going to tell apart, `foo(bar(A))` and `"EU (European Union)"` and `5+(4-3)`. They all fit the function-regex definition. Don't they?

Comment: @sshashank124 I don't mind the questions. Actually it looks like the regular expression that I included in the question, already handles "EU (European Union)" and 5+(4-3) It just doesn't handle the bar in foo(bar(A)) of course.